# Why does sed.exe do nothing?

Tags: windows, sed

On Windows, I'm trying to use GNU sed 4.0.7 from [UnxUtils](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/).

This works…

```
sed "s@<time>@<TIME>@g" < input.txt > output.txt
```

… but this does nothing:

```
sed "s@<time>.+?</time>@@g" < input.txt > output.txt
```

Escaping characters didn't help. Any idea why?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*sed* uses the POSIX regular expression syntax aka [regex(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/regex.7.html) (either the "Extended" or "Basic" variant depending on whether you used `-r` or not).

Non-greedy `+?` and `*?` quantifiers **do not exist** in POSIX regex; they're more of a PCRE thing. If you want to use them, you'll need to use *perl* or some similar tool, e.g.:

```
perl -pe "s@<time>.+?</time>@@g"
```

If you must use sed, this is usually an acceptable workaround:

```
sed -r "s@<time>[^<]+</time>@@g"
```

(Note that even `+` doesn't exist in the (obsolete) Basic variant, so you need `sed -r` to activate Extended mode.)